# locality and establishment not working in google map

Tags: google-maps

I have this options for my autocomplete google map search but when I added the locality and types it wont work.

```
   var options = {
               types:['school'],
                componentRestrictions: {
                    locality:'caloocan',
                    country: 'PH'}
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete), **componentRestrictions** can be used to restrict results to specific groups. Currently, you can use componentRestrictions to filter by country. The country must be passed as as a two-character, ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 compatible country code.

Here is the example from the documentation

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
types: ['(cities)'],
componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

I think the locality part of your code made the errors. Because it is stated in the documentation that "**In general only a single type is allowed**".

> And the (cities) type collection instructs the Places service to
>   return results that match either **locality** or administrative_area3

Try to check the [parameter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete) that you can use for your code.

Comment: how about for the establishments? thank you for pointing the locality part.

Comment: the establishment is for the types like this `types: ['establishment']`

Comment: I think you need to do your part. Just read the documentation link above. To know more and how to properly use Autocomplete Google Map. If this answer helps you, then you can accept it or just upvote it.